# IOException: The stream is closed Hibernate MS SQL JDBC4

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, stream, hibernate-mapping

I receive the following exception when getting a binary stream.

```
    java.io.IOException: The stream is closed.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.BaseInputStream.checkClosed(SimpleInputStream.java:93)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.PLPInputStream.read(PLPInputStream.java:237)
at au.gov.vic.doi.tp.service.binary.dao.BinaryDAOImplTest.retrieveBinary(BinaryDAOImplTest.java:102)
```

I am using: Hibernate 4.1.1, MS SQL Server 2008 and the latest MS SQL JDBC4 driver.
I use the following custom mapping type 'BlobToStreamUserType' to map from SQL Blob (varchar(max)) to InputStream. Hibernate don't appear to provide a type that maps an SQL BLOB to Java InputStream, the MaterializedBlobType only maps an SQL BLOB to Java byte[].

I am using 'rs.getBinaryStream' to return a true binary stream not a stream buffered in memory, the reason being is that we have large images that if multiple users accessed concurrently would cause memory issues.

According to microsoft

> The Microsoft driver follows the JDBC spec with respect to getBinaryStream =>
>   Note: All the data in the returned stream must be read prior to getting the value of any >other column. The next call to a getter method implicitly closes the stream. Also, a stream >may return 0 when the method InputStream.available is called whether there is data >available or not.
>
> So getBinaryStream is designed to return a true stream of bytes.  We return a true stream >of bytes that is NOT buffered in memory, it is a stream that is read right off the wire >from the server response.   You cannot close the contentDataResultSet until you fetch all >the bytes for our implementation.

I have tried setting the hibernate property 'hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary' to true and false however this makes no difference.

Here is my code:

Image entity class showing mapping to custom user type.

```
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.util.Date;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
   import com.google.common.base.Objects;

   @Entity
   @DynamicInsert(false)
   @DynamicUpdate(false)
   @Table(name = "Binary")
   public class Binary
   {
   .........
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    @Type(type = "my.package.BlobToStreamUserType")   
    public InputStream getImageStream()
    {
        return this.imageStream;
    }
    }
```

here is my custom mapping type:

```
public class BlobToStreamUserType implements UserType
{

public int[] sqlTypes()
{
    return new int[]
    { Types.BLOB };
}

public Class returnedClass()
{
    return InputStream.class;
}

public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor session,
        final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException
{
    return rs.getBinaryStream(names[0]);
}

public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement st, final Object value, final int index,
        final SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
{

    if (value != null)
    {
        if (!InputStream.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass()))
        {
            throw new HibernateException(value.getClass().toString() + " cannot be cast to a java.IO.InputStream");
        }
        InputStream inStream = (InputStream) value;
        st.setBinaryStream(index, inStream);
    }
    else
    {
        st.setBytes(index, null);
    }
}

public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException
{
    return ObjectUtils.equals(x, y);
}

public int hashCode(final Object x) throws HibernateException
{
    assert (x != null);
    return x.hashCode();
}

public Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException
{
    return value;
}

public boolean isMutable()
{
    return false;
}

public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException
{
    return original;
}

public Serializable disassemble(final Object value) throws HibernateException
{
    //disassemble() is only called when caching the data in the second-level cache
    // also safe for mutable objects
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

}

and here is my DAO to retrieve the image stream

```
public class BinaryDAOImpl extends AbstractSpringHibernateDAO implements BinaryDAO
{

public Binary getBinary(final String amsAssetId, final String assetMaintainer, final String variant,
        final Integer sequence) throws GetException
{

    try
    {
        Query query = super.getSession().createQuery(
                "from Binary bin where bin.amsAssetId = :amsAssetId and bin.assetMaintainer = :assetMaintainer "
                        + "and bin.variant = :variant and bin.sequence = :sequence");
        query.setParameter("amsAssetId", amsAssetId);
        query.setParameter("assetMaintainer", assetMaintainer);
        query.setParameter("variant", variant);
        query.setParameter("sequence", sequence);
        return query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

N.b The following workaround to bypass hibernate and retrieve the stream directly from the result set works and allows me to read the stream without exception. However I would rather use hibernate mappings to retrieve a true binary stream.

Modified DAO method

```
public Binary getBinary(final String amsAssetId, final String assetMaintainer, final String variant,
        final Integer sequence) throws GetException
{
    try
    {
        Query query = super.getSession().createQuery(
                "from Binary bin where bin.amsAssetId = :amsAssetId and bin.assetMaintainer = :assetMaintainer "
                        + "and bin.variant = :variant and bin.sequence = :sequence");
        query.setParameter("amsAssetId", amsAssetId);
        query.setParameter("assetMaintainer", assetMaintainer);
        query.setParameter("variant", variant);
        query.setParameter("sequence", sequence);
        Binary binary = (Binary) query.uniqueResult();

        final String id = binary.getId();

        // Necessary until Hibernate supports InputStream mapping
        binary.setImageStream(getSession().doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<InputStream>()
        {
                      public InputStream execute(final Connection connection) throws SQLException
                        {
                            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select image from Binary where id=?",
                                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

                            statement.setString(1, id);

                            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

                            return (resultSet.first() ? resultSet.getBinaryStream(1) : null);
                        }
                    }));

        return binary;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried marking the type as a Lob?

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "image")
@Type(type = "my.package.BlobToStreamUserType")   
Blob blob;

public Blob getBlob(){
   return blob;
}
```

And when you need to work with the stream?

```
            final InputStream is;
    try {
        is = blob.getBinaryStream();
                    //do some work
            }
```

It would be helpful to know you could simply get back a Blob
before defining your own type.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who is experiencing this:

**Update your JDBC driver to at least 7.0 or newer.**

This is a *icrosoft JDBC driver issue which was [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/595) in version 6.5.0(preview) or [7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) (final) of their JDBC driver.
The original issue was reported [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/567), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/611) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/633). (for anybody who is interested.)
There is a nice [support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15) where you can see which version fits you best. (Since this is sometimes a question of supported Java version, JDBC Driver Version and JDBC API Version)